# How can I return my OAuth session to Bixby?

Tags: oauth-2.0, bixby

I'm implementing OAuth with the Spotify Web API. Im doing it following the [Authorization Code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).

If I try any utterances, it should pops it to login and then return it to my capsule. However, I can make the login, and when returning it to the capsule, it will not register the OAuth session and will be in a loop asking it to login again.

The following images will show some of my code:

[image]
[image]

localplay.js
[image]

As you can see, I'm just trying to return a boolean value which I will show it in the dialog, as a test.

What am I missing?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Without knowing more about your code, I would point to a misspelling of "responseSucceeded" in your JS `return` as a good place to start debugging.

Comment: Hello @Ameya the misspell matches the action and models counterparts. What else of my code would be helpful to add to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client-secret-key` is not supposed to be the *value* of the secret.

The `client-secret-key` is a name entered in the Config & Secrets screen of the Bixby Developer Center for the capsule.

Please check this documentation for more details: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/authorization.global.oauth2-client-credentials.client-secret-key